# Inference engine prolog

Tags: prolog, inference-engine

I am trying to build an inference engine in prolog.

For example, here are some rules

```
R1 : A and B -> C
R2 : E and F -> D
R3 : G and T -> H
```

I wanted to do it like this

```
c :- a,b
d :- e,f
h :- g,t
```

but I have to use a predicate "rule/1" defined as follows

`rule(Ri) :- "if conditions then conclusions".`

For example :

```
rule(r1) :- "if a and b then c".
```

How can I do ?

Comment: It's a bit unclear how you want your `rule/1` predicate or fact to work. You can say things like, `R1 = ':-'(c,(a,b))` and then `assertz(R1)` will assert the rule, `c :- a,b.`. But you don't seem to be asking for that exactly.

Comment: How exactly do you want to use these predicates?

Comment: ' -1 for not bothering clarify your question/reply the comments over time.

Comment: plus 1 for helping me with my homework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found a solution :

```
:- dynamic if/1, then/1.
rule(r1) :- if([a,b]),then([c]).
rule(r2) :- if([e,f]),then([d]).
rule(r3) :- if([g,t]),then([h]).
```

and then use the predicate `clause/2` to iterate over the rules, like this :

```
clause(rule(R),(if(X),then(Y))).
```